# How do I rotate a 3D object about an axis without changing it's location? (LWJGL)

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation, lwjgl

I'm currently trying to get a composite 3D object that consists of two 3D pyramids to rotate about a given axis by an angle in radians. However, one of the pyramids of the composite object is not staying flush to the other.

In the image below, I am attempting to rotate the left object PI radians about the X axis. However, one of the pyramids doesn't stay in the correct position.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MekFZ.png

Below is the code I am using to to the scale, rotate, and translate.

```
float[] model = { xSize,  0,    0,    0,
                       0,   ySize,  0,    0,
                       0,     0,   zSize, 0,
                      xLoc,  yLoc,  zLoc,    1 };


    FloatBuffer modelBuf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(model.length);

    matrix = new Matrix4f();

    matrix = matrix.scale(xSize, ySize, zSize);
    matrix = matrix.rotateXYZ(dxRot, dyRot, dzRot);
    matrix = matrix.setTranslation(xLoc, yLoc, zLoc);

    modelBuf = matrix.get(modelBuf);

    glUniformMatrix4fv( unif_model, false, modelBuf );
```

Does anybody know why this is could be happening?

Comment: Could you provide the code for 'Matrix4f'?

Comment: https://github.com/JOML-CI/JOML/blob/master/src/org/joml/Matrix4f.java

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you want to group objects. You should use a transform tree for that. I.e. introduce a transformation matrix for the entire group and separate transformation matrices for each object within the group (relative to the group's coordinate system).

In your concrete example, the objects' matrices would consist only of a constant translation and rotation part. They do not change. When rendering the objects, you should set the current transformation matrix as:

```
transform = groupTransform * objectTransform
```

If you want to move, rotate, scale an entire group, apply these transformations only to `groupTransform`.